# Save a file with Names

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a form in word, whenever a submit is clicked upon it send a notification to email address and saves the file to a location. I have a script as below, I want when the data is input in the form and clicked on submit for 2nd time the saved file should have a different name because if the below script is run again it will overwrite the current form which is saved on that location.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim OL              As Object
Dim EmailItem       As Object
Dim Doc             As Document


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Set Doc = ActiveDocument
Doc.Save
Doc.SaveAs2 "d:/abcd.docx"

With EmailItem

    .Subject = "Test"
    .Body = "Test"
    .To = "jaiswalrohitkr@gmail.com"
    .Importance = olImportanceNormal 'Or olImprotanceHigh Or olImprotanceLow
    .Attachments.Add Doc.FullName
    .Send

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set Doc = Nothing
Set OL = Nothing
Set EmailItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I would also like to change the subject line every time it sends an email.

Comment: I would also like to change the subject line every time it sends an email for example Test, Test1, Test2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global counter and the FileSystemObject to accomplish this.

```
'Global Variable to hold our iteration count
Public docCount As Integer
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim OL              As Object
Dim EmailItem       As Object
Dim Doc             As Document
Dim DocName         As String
'add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Dim fso             As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject



Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Set Doc = ActiveDocument
Doc.Save

DocName = "d:/abcd.docx"
'use the fileSystemObject to check if the file already exists
Do While fso.FileExists(DocName) = True
    DocName = "d:/abcd" & CStr(docCount) & ".docx"
    'add one to the counter to check again
    docCount = docCount + 1
Loop
Doc.SaveAs2 DocName

With EmailItem
    If docCount > 0 Then
        'more than one iteration so adjust name
        .Subject = "Test" & CStr(docCount)
    Else
        'first iteration so leave it as test
        .Subject = "Test"
    End If
    .Body = "Test"
    .To = "jaiswalrohitkr@gmail.com"
    .Importance = olImportanceNormal 'Or olImprotanceHigh Or olImprotanceLow
    .Attachments.Add Doc.FullName
    .Send

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set Doc = Nothing
Set OL = Nothing
Set EmailItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: that did not work. Let me know if I can share a file and you can guide me step by step.

Comment: you need to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting runtime in your VBA project

Comment: how do we achieve it, can you let me know step by step the procedure to do it?

Comment: In Excel click the Developer tab, then click Visual Basic to launch the VBA Editor.  When the editor opens click Tools then References.  Scroll through the list until you find Microsoft Scripting runtime  and place a check by it and click ok.

Comment: The arrow is highlighting to Private Sub                                                                                                  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim bStarted As Boolean
 Dim oOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
 'You'll need to add the Outlook Object Library to VBA Tools References
 Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem

Comment: Did you add the reference to the Outlook object model?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, also can we have it without macro. A macro free file.